# limit user input by php

Tags: php, validation, input, special-characters

I have a username textbox. It should only accept between 3 and 10 characters and it should only accept (0, 9) and (A , Z ) values or maybe (- and _),
nothing more
.

And if the user inputs a value like $%^# it should give an error
I want to do this with PHP, not Jquery. Can anyone help me with this?

I know I can use

```
<input name="1" type="text" value="1" maxlength="10" />
```

But it doesn't give an error to the user and just filters the input value.

Thank you.

Comment: What PHP solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: preg_match but i dont know Rules of this Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regular expression could work

```
if (preg_match("%^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{3,10}$%", $_POST["1"])) {
    // OK
} else {
    // ERROR
}
```

Comment: Regular expressions is your friend :), i'm just getting deeper into that part myself and it makes life a lot easier.

Comment: /^[\w-]{3,10}$/ to be more concise, keep in mind these won't allow spaces in the value, to allow spaces as well use /^[ \w-]{3,10}$/

Comment: @masiharastooyi Mark the answer as accepted if it helped you masih :)

Comment: /^[ \w-]{3,10}$/ and /^[ \w-]{3,10}$/  are same :/

Comment: can i ask another question ? how its possible to let user input <Br> and <a>  but not other html value in Textarea?

Answer (score 0):

When the value is submitted to your PHP script, you can look at it via the `$_REQUEST` global variable. In this case, you would reference `$_REQUEST["1"]`. To make sure the value it contains is of a certain size, use the `strlen()` function. To make sure that the value only contains certain characters, you can use `preg_match_all()` and an appropriate regular expression like the following:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]
```

Comment: Or do it all with SnapGravy's gravylicious regex.